# Getting a substring from a std::string with iterators

Tags: c++, string, iterator, std

I want to get a substring from the first appearance of char in string to the end of the string. I thought that I can just use constructor, like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004395/getting-a-substring-of-a-stdstring-between-two-iterators), but it doesn't really work.
When I do like this:

```
string(input.find(' ')+1, input.end()-1)
```

I face "no constructor" error

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__cxx11::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')
```

How can I fix this problem and get my code working?

Comment: @Yashas any non-empty string with char from input.find and some other symbols, like "Stack overflow"

Comment: find does not return an iterator, this is the problem you have

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that `input` is a `std::string`

If you take a look at the documentation of `std::string::find`, you'll find that it returns the index of the found character; not an iterator. In order to use the iterator constructor, you must use:

```
auto str = std::string(input.begin() + input.find(' '), input.end());
```

Alternatively, you could use `substr` member of `input`:

```
auto str = input.substr(input.find(' '));
```

---

The +1 and -1 in your example are confusing. If you add 1 to first, then you get the substring starting *after* the found character, not starting from the character. If you subtract 1 from the end, you copy until one before the last character, not up to the end of the string.

---

Note that you probably also need to also handle the case where the character is not found. The constructor approach (as I've implemented) would have undefined behaviour. The `substr` approach would throw an exception.

Comment: You actually don't need the second argument for `substr` as you need to go up to the end ;)

Comment: @Yashas I had assumed that OP wanted substring up to one before the end as per the example code. That appears to conflict with the description though...

Comment: Oh, I see. The example code and the description conflict with each other. I think the OP does not want the space to be a part of the substring so you would have to add a +1 to the index before passing to `substr`.

Comment: won't the first solution be UB if the space is not found?

Answer (score 1):

The `find` member function of `std::string` does not return an iterator.

There is also [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) which you can use as `input.substr(input.find(' ') + 1);`

Comment: But why can't I use constructor as in question i mentioned?

Comment: because `input.find` does not return an iterator

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of defensive programming, you may want to consider the pathalogical case where there is no space in the `input`.

Here are two solutions, one using iterators and standard algorithms, the other using string's `find` method.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::string 
all_after_space_iters(std::string const& input)
{
    auto last = input.end();

    auto after_found = [&]
    {
        auto current = std::find(input.begin(), last, ' ');
        if (current != last)
            current = std::next(current);
        return current;
    };

    return std::string(after_found(), last);
}


std::string 
all_after_space_no_iters(std::string const& input)
{
    auto pos = input.find(' ');

    auto result = std::string();
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        result = input.substr(pos + 1);
    }
    return result;
}

std::string check(std::string s)
{
    if (s.empty())
        s = "**empty**";
    return s;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << check(all_after_space_iters("dog cat")) << '\n';
    std::cout << check(all_after_space_no_iters("dog cat")) << '\n';
    std::cout << check(all_after_space_iters("dogcat")) << '\n';
    std::cout << check(all_after_space_no_iters("dogcat")) << '\n';
}
```

Expected Output:

```
cat
cat
**empty**
**empty**
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44e484d3325d195e

Note: these are examples only. There are many ways to skin this cat.